# How can i set include_root_in_json to false for all my RoR models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, activemodel

How can i set include_root_in_json to false for all my RoR models?

I've tried to set ActiveModel::Base.include_root_in_json = false inside application.rb, but it has no effect.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Model.to_json method is used to returns a JSON string representing the model and i have used 
**self.include_root_in_json = false** in a model itself.

But for the whole application you can try setting **ActiveModel::Base.include_root_in_json = false** in an initializer.[edit This does not work.]

[edit] **ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = true** try adding this line to config/environment.rb file.

Comment: this also works for me self.include_root_in_json = false, but ActiveModel::Base.include_root_in_json = false cause an error, like it is not defined. (I'm using Rails 3)

Comment: Can you try putting the following line in config/environment.rb

ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = false

Comment: I've got an initializer in config/initializers/active_record.rb that contains `ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = false` and it works fine for me (I'm using Rails 3.0.4). Something you have to remember (it used to catch me out) is if you change an initializer, you need to restart your server or reload your console for it to take effect.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if this is true for the later versions of rails but for me (running 2.3.5 atm) there was already a declaration for this setting in /config/initializers/new_rails_defaults.rb where it was set to:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = true
```

So if you try to set this setting in another place then it might be overridden.

Comment: +1 works for me by changing "true" to "false" in `config/initializers/new_rails_defaults.rb`.

Answer (score 2):

On Rails 3.2.2, this is already set in the initializers:

---`config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb` ---

```
# Disable root element in JSON by default.
ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
  self.include_root_in_json = false
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For default system wide config is alway good idea to set variable in initializers, like config/initializers/defaults.rb

Answer (score 1):

I think you should set ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = false in config/application.rb

not ActiveModel::Base

Answer (score 0):

At Rails 4 in "config/initializers/wrap_elements.rb" you can uncomment the following:

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
 self.include_root_in_json = true
end
```